# Event profile picture not shown in Graph API v9.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to get the event profile picture from Graph API Explorer for a page (fans' page) that I manage.

I inserted the url below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/{event-id}/picture
```

However, whichever event-id I inserted, I always got empty result like this:

```
{
    "data": [
      
    ]
}
```

Anyone knows why?

Many thanks.

Comment: did you try with a page token of that page?

Comment: Yes. Already. I can get the event name, descriptions...etc. It's just that I can't get the picture.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `cover` field? Not sure if events actually have a `picture`.

Comment: After replacing picture with cover, I got the following message:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid edge (cover) on node type (Event)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}`